# UITableView re-order last row removed (framework bug or working as intended ?)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm think this might be a framework bug, I've dumbed it down to an extremely simple and static example (code below) here are the circumstances:

- Allow re-ordering rows, to any position except the last position
- If user tries to drop it onto the last row, propose to drop back to the original position

Here is how to trigger the bug:

- take one of the first rows and re-order-drag all the way down to the last row (where user is not allowed to drop it), keep dragging it, but drag it back up and drop it somewhere in an allowed location, while still being able view the last row. It's important that the row, which is being dropped is an off-screen row (original position not visible in the final drop location)
- the last row will disappear from the view
- `didEndDisplaying cell` is not called for the last row
- scrolling up and down will result in a bugged view state, where the empty view will appear 'somewhere'
- scrolling around a bit more will eventually fix the issue again

I don't think this is working as intended, but with some more testing, I have the suspicion that the indexPaths returned from `proposedDestinationIndexPath` have to be monotonic, e.g. if dragging index 4 and returned `5,6...14` before, you can't go back to the `sourceIndex (4)`, but you'll have to lock to highest allowed index (14 in this example)

I'm curious if anyone has details or anything official regarding this. What is allowed and what isn't ?

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private var rows: [RowData] = [
        RowData("1"),
        RowData("2"),
        RowData("3"),
        RowData("4"),
        RowData("5"),
        RowData("6"),
        RowData("7"),
        RowData("8"),
        RowData("9"),
        RowData("10"),
        RowData("11"),
        RowData("12"),
        RowData("13"),
        RowData("14"),
        RowData("15")
    ]
    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        // ADVANCED VIEW
        tableView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        tableView.rowHeight = 120
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        //
        tableView.register(SpyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "default_row")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
//        tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = false
//        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rows.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "default_row", for: indexPath)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = rows[indexPath.row].title
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
//    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
//        false
//    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .none
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let removed = self.rows.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        self.rows.insert(removed, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        // uncomment to confirm data is properly inserted
//        for row in self.rows {
//            print("row: \(row)")
//        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
        if proposedDestinationIndexPath.row >= rows.count - 1 {
            return sourceIndexPath
            // BELOW WORKS as expected and doesn't cause the error
//            return IndexPath(row: rows.count - 2, section: 0)
        } else {
            return proposedDestinationIndexPath
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didEndDisplaying cell : \(cell.textLabel?.text ?? "unexpected")")
    }
}

class RowData {
    let title: String
    
    init(_ title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class SpyCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override func removeFromSuperview() {
        print("removeFromSuperview() \(textLabel?.text ?? "unexpected")")
        super.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that this use of willDisplay and didEndDisplaying is wrong? What happens if you delete those and do this properly?

Comment: @matt I don't think there is anything wrong with the use of both of them. But I removed both of them for testing and set the textLabel directly in `cellForRowAt`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due attempting to remove and insert into the same position.  If you change your `moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath` function to not move the row when the source and destination are the same, you don't see the bug.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    if sourceIndexPath.row != destinationIndexPath.row {
        let removed = self.rows.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        self.rows.insert(removed, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
}
```

Edit:  Here's a video with this fix in place, I'm not seeing the bug you describe:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ8Zy.jpg.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately the issue remains. I also debugged it and moveRowTo is only called once the row is dropped. (usually not the same row).
Remember to trigger the bug:
1. The dragged row has to be a offscreen row
2. You have to drag it over the last row and then move back up before letting it go

Comment: Check my edit, I added a video with the fix in place, isn't it working how it should?

Comment: @clawseome no, after dragging all the way down, drag back up and place the view between 13 and 14, number 15 will then just disappear.
P.S. thank you for putting so much work into this !

Comment: @Su-AuHwang Can you clarify that you only want to prevent the user from moving the cell to be the very last row?  For example, if there are 15 cells, they can only drop the cell so it's the 14th or lower?  Because your code looks to prevent them from being able to drop the cell to both the last and 2nd to last position

Comment: this is just an example, important to trigger the bug is only the last row.